# Compatible CPUs in this motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, architecture, processor-socket

[image: Motherboard]

It says GA-T672FXME & L-S672G.

1.How can I know which CPUs are compatible??

2.How can I tell what type of socket does it use and what is it’s architecture??

3.Also which out of the two is model number and serial number?(Please drop down some tips on identification of the same for other boards as well)

Answer (score 1):

If you just search both the numbers in Google, you will find information on one of the numbers. On the 'GA' number, I found that [it](https://www.visionit.in/product/motherboard-for-lenovo-ga-t672fxme-l-s672g-genericassembled-computer-system-2/) is from Lenovo and has a LGA 775 socket and that it has a D945 chipset and it uses DDR2 memory. And [here](http://www.cpu-world.com/Sockets/Socket%20775%20(LGA775).html) is an article with all of the compatible CPUs that physically fit, you will have to look though if they are supported but looking at the age of that motherboard, your best bet is to just pick the cheapest and oldest.(not really worth spending a lot of money on)

Comment: I wonder how you were able to find this much information,I tried a lot was unsuccessful

Comment: I just have in lying around and was looking if it was worth selling or to be sent to recycle

Comment: Next time, you search, just add motherboard at the end and use one number of the two at a time, this will increase your results by a lot. And you probably will only get $ 10 or less, new motherboards these days can cost less then $ 50.

Comment: Thank you for the tips